# Break if statement in python

Tags: python, loops

i have mistake with my python code. There's mini game about guessing code. i want to break if statements and make else statement (activated when i guess wrong letter).Here's the code. Return and break function outputs: "return/break function outside the loop". Please, modify the code :D 
`

```
import time
print('Oto jest gra, w której musisz odgadnąć kod! Kod ma 4 litery!')
decyzja = input('Chcesz grać? T/N\n')
if decyzja == "t" or "T":
    one = input('Wpisz 1 litere\n')
    if one == "k":
        two = input('Wpisz 2 Litere\n')
        if two == "u":
            three = input('Wpisz 3 litere\n')
            if three == "b":
                four = input('Ostatnia!\n')
                if four == "a":
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print('Zgadles kod!!!')
```

`

Comment: Use a loop it is really bad practice to rewrite same thing repeatedly

Comment: I think English factors into this a bit but it's impossible for me to know what this code is supposed to do sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: "breaking out" of if statement inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022631/python-breaking-out-of-if-statement-inside-a-for-loop)

Comment: despite it not being a loop, something like this would help.

Comment: There is no loop in this piece of code. You can use `while` loop here may be and break when user guesses the right character but really not sure what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Thanks mad, i will test it EDIT: It isn't working :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (it's better to use a function):

```
import time

def numguess(myinput):
    if decyzja.lower() == "t":
        one = input('Wpisz 1 litere\n')
    else:
        return False

    if one == "k":
        two = input('Wpisz 2 Litere\n')
    else:
        return False

    if two == "u":
        three = input('Wpisz 3 litere\n')
    else:
        return False

    if three == "b":
        four = input('Ostatnia!\n')
    else:
        return False

    if four == "a":
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Zgadles kod!!!')
    else:
        return False

print('Oto jest gra, w której musisz odgadnąć kod! Kod ma 4 litery!')

decyzja = input('Chcesz grać? T/N\n')

numguess(decyzja)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would template it like this

```
for letter in "tkuba":
    user_input = input().lower()
    if user_input == letter:
        print("...")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: But... first letter is for confirming you want to play. How can i do to get big and small character work?

Comment: input().lower() and the complete string input is in lowecase